# What to import to use @SuppressFBWarnings?

Tags: java, include, findbugs, spotbugs

What to import to use SuppressFBWarnings? 
I installed the findbugs plugin via help / install new software
When I type import edu., I can't do ctrl space to get the options.

Example

```
try {
  String t = null;
  @edu.umd.cs.findbugs.annotations.SuppressFBWarnings(
    value="NP_ALWAYS_NULL", 
    justification="I know what I'm doing")
  int sl = t.length();
  System.out.printf( "Length is %d", sl );
} catch (Throwable e) {
...
}
```

Has error "edu cannot be resolved to a type"

Answer (score 36):

In order to use the FindBugs annotations, you need to include *annotations.jar* and *jsr305.jar* from the FindBugs distribution on your classpath. If you are sure that you want the `@SuppressFBWarnings` annotation only (and not the [others](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/annotations.html)), then *annotations.jar* alone would be sufficient.

You can find the two JARs in the *lib* folder of the [FindBugs distribution](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/downloads.html).

If you are using Maven:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you are using Gradle:

```java
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:3.0.1'
    compileOnly 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:3.0.1'
}
```

`compileOnly` is the Gradle flavor of what Maven calls `provided` scope.

---

**Update for SpotBugs (2018):**

FindBugs has been superseded by [SpotBugs](https://spotbugs.github.io/). So if you are already using SpotBugs, the [migration guide](http://spotbugs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migration.html) suggests that you use the following dependencies instead:

> Please depend on both of *spotbugs-annotations* and *net.jcip:jcip-annotations:1.0* instead.

Maven:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.jcip</groupId>
    <artifactId>jcip-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>spotbugs-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.3</version>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Gradle:

```java
dependencies {
    compileOnly 'net.jcip:jcip-annotations:1.0'
    compileOnly 'com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-annotations:3.1.3'
}
```

If you also used `jsr305`, that dependency remains the same as above.

Comment: why `optional` and not `provided` for spotbugs dependencies?

Comment: [Optional vs. Provided](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40393098/1005481) is a nice discussion. Here, it does not matter, as the dependencies are not needed at runtime. However, they must of course be on the classpath of the analysis run. @JakubBochenski

Comment: I think `provided` is actually a better fit here. Optional dependencies are not packaged into wars, but some people consider it a bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MWAR-351
However there is no (easy) way to exclude optional dependencies from maven assembly, whereas you can do that easily for `provided` scoped ones

Comment: I agree - which is why I used `provided`. The bottom part of my answer is a copy from the linked SpotBugs migration guide, and *they* preferred `optional`. Still, from a FindBugs/SpotBugs perspective, it doesn't matter, so you can use whatever suits you and your existing build process.

Comment: In 2020, I used the single dependency: `implementation('com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-annotations:4.0.0-RC3')`. I'm not sure if that would cover all cases here, but FWIW.

Comment: In 2021, ```implementation 'com.github.spotbugs:spotbugs-annotations:4.5.0'``` from [SpotBugs GitHub](https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs)
following @mm2001 last update.

Comment: Interestingly, one does not need any external jars. If you define your own SuppressFBWarnings annotation with CLASS retention, you can use that instead.  The SpotBugs code literally looks only at the name of the annotation class, and it accept any annotation ending with "SuppressWarnings" or "SuppressFBWarnings" regardless of package.

The SpotBugs annotations.jar file is small though, and it's simple to include that.