# FindBugs Warning removal

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, compilation, findbugs

I am getting following error while running FindBugs:

> Bug type NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH.

The code giving error is below:

```java
List<Request> reviewerList = null;
    
response = restAPI CAll // assume some rest call.
reviewerListDto = response.getBody(); //it never returns null

// this check is added because of find bugs, else it wont allow to access getReviewers() method 
if (reviewerListDto!=null) { 
    reviewerList = reviewerListDto.getReviewers();
}
// HERE is the point I am stuck 
for (Request reviewer : reviewerList) {
    reviewer.setPullrequestId(pullrequest.getId());
    reviewer.setRepositoryId(pullrequest.getRepositoryId());
}
```

The error is coming because the `reviewerList` can be empty as per FindBugs in for loop. But I know that it will never be `null`. One way to remove it to check `reviewerList` for `null` before for loop, but is there any other way?

Comment: `reviewerList` remains `null` if `reviewerListDto` equals `null`

Comment: yes but reviewerListDto will never be null. I added that if condition eviewerListDto!=null because of find bug warning

Comment: I believe that by adding `if(reviewerListDto!=null) {` you are instructing Findbugs that `response.getBody` can in fact return `null`.

Comment: but if I dont put if, then i cannot access reviewerListDto.getReviewers(); becasue it thinks it can be NPE

Answer (score 0):

You can [use `@SuppressFBWarnings` if you add `com.google.code.findbugs:annotations` to the classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39412365/10871900):

```java
@SuppressFBWarnings(value="NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH", justification="This can never be null")
```

However, it is basically the same as why you put the `if`-statement, there. When adding an if-statements, you say that it could be that way and the code is only executed if that happens. If the if statement is always executed, there is no reason for an if statement.

So, you can also suppress the if statement and ignore the warning that caused you to add the if statement.

Another way would be to just put the code using `reviewerList` inside the if statement or to throw an exception (e.g. an `AssertionError`) if it is null (or use `assert` right-away).

```java
List<Request> reviewerList = null;
// response = restAPI CAll // assume some rest call.
reviewerListDto = response.getBody(); //it never returns null
assert reviewerListDto!=null;
reviewerList = reviewerListDto.getReviewers();
for (Request reviewer : reviewerList) {
    reviewer.setPullrequestId(pullrequest.getId());
    reviewer.setRepositoryId(pullrequest.getRepositoryId());
}
```

Comment: what is the good practice here? For me, it is to check list for null instead of assert and suppress.

Comment: If you check for null, you should put the code using `reviewerList` in the `if`, too **and** think of what should happen if it is null.